# how to configure ssl for a subdomain on nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

Currently Nginx is configured so that it accepts a wildcard SSL certificate for domain ex: *.website.com.

Instead of buying an expensive wildcard certificate I bought a single domain SSL certificate for the top domain website.com

Now, I found out that the service actually uses two subdomains that also need to be under SSL.

ex: a.website.com and b.website.com

Question.

How do I change the nginx configuration so that when I buy a single subdomain SSL certificate for a.website.com I can point nginx to use it.

Here is what the Nginx file currently looks like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.io www.website.io;
        return 301 https://website.io$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl on;
        server_name website.io www.website.io;
    client_max_body_size 5m;
        add_header X-UA-Compatible    "IE=Edge,chrome=1";

    access_log /var/log/nginx/website.io_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/website.io_error.log;  

        ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/website.io/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/website.io/ssl.key;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        location /500.html {
                root  /srv/static/website/maintenance;
        }

        location / {
        #auth_basic            "Restricted";
                #auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/htpasswd.conf;

                include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_connect_timeout 30;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 30;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.4:3031;
        }
}
```

Comment: Add one more server block for `a.example.com`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your config would turn into something like this (I've changed the domains in your example to the domains `a.website.com` and `b.website.com` as per the body of your question for clarity)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name a.website.com;
        return 301 https://a.website.com$request_uri;
        }   

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name a.website.com;
        client_max_body_size 5m;
        add_header X-UA-Compatible    "IE=Edge,chrome=1";

        access_log /var/log/nginx/a.website_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/a.website_error.log;  

        ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/a.website/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/a.website/ssl.key;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        location /500.html {
                root  /srv/static/website/maintenance;
        }

        location / {
                #auth_basic            "Restricted";
                #auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/htpasswd.conf;
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_connect_timeout 30;
                uwsgi_read_timeout 30;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.4:3031;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name b.website.com;
        return 301 https://b.website.com$request_uri;
        }   

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name b.website.com;
        client_max_body_size 5m;
        add_header X-UA-Compatible    "IE=Edge,chrome=1";

        access_log /var/log/nginx/b.website.com_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/b.website.com_error.log;  

        ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/b.website.com/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/b.website.com/ssl.key;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        location /500.html {
                root  /srv/static/website/maintenance;
        }

        location / {
                #auth_basic            "Restricted";
                #auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/htpasswd.conf;
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_connect_timeout 30;
                uwsgi_read_timeout 30;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.4:3031;
        }
}
```

You can repeat this for as many sites as required, it just defines an additional server block(s) for each site

Comment: so do you need 2 SSL certificates (one for a.website.com and one for b.website.com) ?

Comment: @laguittemh yes unless it is a domain that can be covered using a wildcard certificate

Comment: Note that this strategy requires TLS SNI support on both server and client

Comment: @MestreLion which seems to be 99.14 % per https://caniuse.com/sni