# Nginx config is not reading location for subdomain

Tags: nginx, https

Hello i am new to nginix , i am trying to do couple of things

1. if main or sub domain is not https then redirect to https
2. Load/read location config for respective block
3. Load/read subdomain config rather than main domain config

   ```
    server {

    if ($host = example.net) {
        return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
    }
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.net www.example.net;
    return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;

    }

    server {

    if ($host = in.example.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen       80;
    server_name  in.example.net;
    return 301 https://in.example.net$request_uri;
   }
   ```

My main domain config :

```
server {
  server_name  example.net;

 location / {

proxy_pass http://myip:8089;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

rewrite ^/$ /app/usa/home break;

}

 listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
 include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

My subdomain config :

```
server {
    server_name  uk.example.net;
  
location / {

    proxy_pass http://myip:8089;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    rewrite ^/$ /app/uk/home break;
    
    }
    
     listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
     include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
}

}
```

**Issue** : When i load uk.example.net , it loads/reads main domain (example.net) location config

1. How do i improve ?
2. What is wrong i am doing ?
3. What is recommended if i have multiple subdomains in future ?

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you have that first block with the if statements? Typically you have your main server block serving domain.com on https, another server block forwarding all http, and a third block with a certificate for www.domain.com that has ssl cert / config with forwarding. Treat each domain as separate. There's many examples online.

Comment: yes bit of not good config , understood. Let me check , If you have a example please share.
is it like main config, then subdmain config, then https redirect blocks ?

Comment: Refereed this and it is better and simple way to understand now https://serverfault.com/questions/729408/how-to-configure-ssl-for-a-subdomain-on-nginx/729423